# How to find out if there is stopwords and count if exist

Tags: python, pandas, stop-words

I have a csv file that contains list of sentences in rows, i wanted to find out if there are any stopwords in each rows, return 1 if exist else return 0. And if return 1, i want to count the stopwords. Below are my codes so far, i was only able to get all of the stopwords that exist in the csv, but not for each rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import nltk
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk import sent_tokenize,word_tokenize
from collections import Counter
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')

top_N = 10

news=pd.read_csv("split.csv",usecols=['STORY'])

newss = news.STORY.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ').str.cat(sep=' ')
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(newss)
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
words_except_stop_dist = nltk.FreqDist(w for w in words if w not in stopwords)


rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
print(rslt)
```

This is the truncated csv file

```
id    STORY
0     In the bag
1     What is your name
2     chips, bag
```

I would like to save the output to a new csv file, the expected output should look like this

```
id    STORY                exist     How many
0     In the bag            1           2
1     What is your name     1           4
2     chips bag             0           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"story":['In the bag', 'what is your name', 'chips, bag']})
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
df['clean'] = df['story'].apply(lambda x : nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(x.lower().replace(r',', ' ')))
df
    story               clean   
0   In the bag          [in, the, bag]
1   what is your name   [what, is, your, name]
2   chips, bag          [chips, bag]

df['clean'] = df.clean.apply(lambda x : [y  for y in x if y in stopwords])
df['exist'] = df.clean.apply(lambda x : 1 if len(x) > 0 else 0)
df['how many'] = df.clean.apply(lambda x : len(x)) 

df

    story               clean              exist    how many
0   In the bag          [in, the]              1    2
1   what is your name   [what, is, your]       1    3
2   chips, bag          []                     0    0
```

Note: You can change regex as per your requirements. you can drop `clean` column or keep it if you need it later.